# how to extract the features and labels from csv file to use them in the classifier fitting?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification

[the photo showing my dataset.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfuKm.png)

the above photo showing my .csv data. i used the basic code to split the data to training and testing sets 80/20 as showing below in the code.
the problem is i don't know how to fit the data into the classifier (clf.fit(features, labels)) i have three features (pdb, pds and pdsh) and three labels (big, compact and small) how to extract them from the csv file?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('pd.csv')
df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)

splt = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.8

train = df[splt]
test = df[~splt]

#The svm classifier 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(features, labels)
result = clf.predict(featuresT)
print(accuracy_score(TestLabels, result)*100)
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Please search your problems on internet as solutions are available. I am still writing one.**

Firstly the labels should be converted to numeric 0, 1, 2.

As you are using pandas, You can extract labels by **label = df['Name']**. But now you have to drop target column from both train and test dataset.

To drop column use:

**train = train.drop(['Name'],axis=1)**

**test = test.drop(['Name'],axis=1)**